# conflicting filter command in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the usual `filter` R command. However, when I run this on some `data.frame`, such basic as `filter(data,data$entry==some_data)`, the output is a time serie. This is obviously related to the time series libraries I imported. How can I fix it ?

I imported the following libraries

`library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(stringi)
library(gridExtra)
library(rCharts)
library(xts)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
library(curl)
library(vars)
library(astsa)
library(urca)
library(fGarch)`

Comment: use dplyr::filter(), you have to reference the library if you think a function is being masked

Comment: also when specifying what function you are using, it would be good to say what package it came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `filter` when you start R is `stats::filter`, it is used on time series. `dplyr` should mask it when loaded, so maybe you didn't load `dplyr`? Or maybe another package you loaded afterwards masked the `dplyr` version...

You can always specify the version you need by using `package::function` notation, e.g., `dplyr::filter(data, ...)`. You can also check on conflicts (multiple definitions of objects) with `conflicts()`.

---

As a side note, you should not be using `$` inside `dplyr::filter` for the data you pass in, it is built to work with unquoted column names:

```
filter(data,data$entry==some_data) # bad
filter(data, entry == some_data)   # good
```